# Find Python compilation / runtime error before running

Tags: python, compiler-errors, runtime-error

Consider the following:

```
def func_a(param1,param2):
    print (param1 + param2)

func_a("a")
```

`func_a` expects two parameters, whereas it is called with only one.
In other languages this kind of error is discovered while coding or compiling.

Is it possible to find this Python coding error before runtime?

Comment: Since, in Python it's also possible to dynamically redefine `func_a` at runtime, it makes this sort of static analysis difficult to do correctly -- some IDEs may support some limited checking though.

Comment: You might want to use PyCharm or a similar IDE. PyCharm does highlight this sort of errors in trivial cases, but it is impossible to highlight them for decorated functions and the like.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I do use PyCharm. However it does not highlight this error, and alike. Also, even if maybe it does and it is only a question of settings of my IDE, in large projects, one have to go line by line over all files. isn't it?

Comment: @OJNSim I usually review the error list in PyCharm, instead of investigating all files line-by-line. The example you've presented is trivial for PyCharm's static analyser, and I've checked that it does report this issue. If you have something more complicated (i.e. decorated functions, `*args` and `**kwargs` parameters), it might strugle, because Python's type system provides few static guarantees. There are ways to impose a more static type system, but that would be unpythonic and break code compatibility/maintainability. You might want to try coding most of your modules in Cython, though.

Comment: @jedwards what do you mean redefine at runtime? and anyway, all these errors are true at one point, if one changes signature at design time (or runtime as you say), so the error might not be relevant any more. This is true in all languages.

Comment: @OJNSim it means, that at any moment during the runtime, the name you use for a function can be reassigned to another function (that's how decorators work). Since decorators can alter a function's signature in any possible way, there is little a static analyser can do.

Comment: @EliKorvigo how do review the error list? Are these kind of errors are highlighted in the editor? do you have to do something in order to see them? I now found the `Inspect Code` option in the code menu. Is this the way you do it? execute this whenever you want to check for errors?

Comment: @OJNSim the list of errors is shown on the right-hand side as coloured ticks. You can hover your mouse over any one of them to review the error and the code block involved. You might want to customise the inspections, but the error in your example should be reported by default. You can also add type-annotations to your code to help PyCharm's static analyser identify type errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@eliKorvigo comment(s) answer the questions.
PyCharm `Inspect code` provide the option of finding (possible) error before runtime.

Comment: You can also checkout the official [mypy plugin for PyCharm](https://github.com/dropbox/mypy-PyCharm-plugin).

Comment: Anyone knows an equivalent for VSCode?